# Fixed elements of an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $u$ is an automorphism of a field $K$, the
>   elements of $K$ fixed by $u$ form a subfield.

How do you prove this?

Comment: It's not hard at all. Just follow the definitions. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm just looking for a formal proof. I'm not a student.

Comment: You've not helped your Readers to provide useful responses by being so terse.  Where do you get stuck in showing the indicated subset of $K$ is a subfield?  What conditions are required to make $S \subset K$ a field?

Comment: How is providing a proof not useful mate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u(0)=u(0+0)=u(0)+u(0)$ implies $u(0)=0$.

$u(1)=u(1\cdot1)=u(1)u(1)$ implies $u(1)=1$ or $u(1)=0$.
If $u(1)=0$, then $u$ is not injective and cannot be an automorphism. So, $u(1)=1$.

If $x$ and $y$ are fixed by $u$, then $u(x+y)=u(x)+u(y)=x+y$ and $u(xy)=u(x)u(y)=xy$.

If $x$ is fixed by $u$, then $0=u(0)=u(x+(-x))=u(x)+u(-x)=x+u(-x)$ and so $u(-x)=-x$.

If $x\ne0$ is fixed by $u$, then $1=u(1)=u(x\cdot x^{-1})=u(x)u(x^{-1})=xu(x^{-1})$ and so $u(x^{-1})=x^{-1}$.

So, the set of elements that are fixed by $u$ contains $0$ and $1$, and is closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, and so is a subfield of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

The first questions that should com to your mind are: What is $u(0)$? What is $u(1)=1$? If $u(a)=a$ and $u(b)=b$, what can you say about$u(a+b)$ and $u(ab)$.

Comment: I'm assuming $u(0)$ and $u(1)$ are both fixed for any automorphism.